# Invalid facebook key hash when app is published on playstore

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I recently published my app on playstore i thought everything is fine suddenly a pop up error message showed up when trying to sign in with facebook:

Invalid key hash : the key hash ### doesn t match any stored keys hashes..

But when releasing the app on my phone or emulator it works fine.

What i did is getting the hash key in two methods:

1- Using code

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.packagename", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

2- Using command prompt

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alahedclubsuperfinal -keystore "ahedclubsuperfinal.jks" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" sha1 -bnary | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\openssl" base64
```

In both ways i am getting **same hash key** and i set it on facebook dev account.

But what i am still getting this error when app is published on playstore?